# How to programmatically run a Loadrunner scenario?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

The current method of running a scenario that I use is via the ALM UI.

Is there a way to this programmatically? That is be able to login to a project and run a scenario given its path.

I found a few resources on use of command line arguments but I'm not sure if they are relevant. The controller for the scenarios are on remote systems.

I want to be able to login to a project and run the scenario (controller is pre-assigned in the scenario).

Edit: http://www.consulting-bolte.de/index.php/hp-alm-rest-api/114-connect-to-hp-alm-via-browser-using-rest-api Found a good place to start here.

Edit 2: Failed to find information on running scenarios in the Loadrunner REST API documentation.

Comment: Do you mean running the controller on a scenario without configuring the UI first? You have to run the scenario through some controller.

Comment: All I wanted to do was kickoff a Loadrunner test without having to login to the UI. I have found a solution in the REST APIs provided by HP Loadrunner.

Comment: Oh you meant PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer here:
http://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.50/api_refs/Performance_Center_REST_API/Performance_Center_REST_API.htm#authenticate.htm%3FTocPath%3DResources%7C_____1

```
http://<PcServer>/LoadTest/rest/domains/alex-qc/projects/PCdemo/Runs
Content-Type: application/xml
Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY={LwssoCookie};QCSession={QCSessionCookie};

<Run xmlns="http://www.hp.com/PC/REST/API">
 <PostRunAction>Collate And Analyze</PostRunAction>
 <TestID>5</TestID>
 <TestInstanceID>4</TestInstanceID>
 <TimeslotDuration>
 <Hours>1</Hours>
 <Minutes>30</Minutes>
 </TimeslotDuration>
 <VudsMode>false</VudsMode>
</Run>
```